# Windows Phone 7 checking for Internet Connection

Tags: windows-phone-7, wifi, windows-phone-7-emulator

```
Dim _isNetworkAvailable = Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled
```

always returns false though I do have internet connection.
I'm testing on the emulator, could that be the source of the issue?

How I'm testing: 
I have a button that calls the above code and displays the result of the boolean in a textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code only check whether Wifi enabled or not on the device, which will always return false if you run in emulator. Because there is no interface to set Wifi enabled in WP7 emulator. You need to use `IsNetworkAvailable` property instead, to check if any internet connection available. See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.isnetworkavailable%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for reference. So your code should be as follow :

```
Dim _isNetworkAvailable = Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable
```

Comment: but that always gives a true answer even if i do not have internet enabled on my computer. checked that out and i figured it should work on a real device. thank you for the answer! One concern though is why would i want to check for network connectivity and not wifi? whats the difference?

Comment: network connectivity can be a cellular connection or wifi connection. So if you enabled packet data on a WP device, you can still have an internet connection despite wifi is not enabled or not connected to any wifi hotsopt